# How to connect to a particular share after automatic connection to a network drive after a Mac start up?

Tags: macos, network, nas

There are solutions I can find how to automatically connect to a network drive whenever the Mac starts up, such as

```
smb://synology.local
```

But this drive has many shares, such as `Public`, `Private` and `Backup`.

How would you automatically connect to `Backup` as well, assuming some other automated tool needs to access the path `/Volumes/Backup`?  (using any Settings, app, or Bash / Zsh commands or script that can be added to system startup?)

Answer (score 2):

Just connect to the share that you want to connect to on startup.

Then, add that to your Login Items under your account in User & Groups in your Systems Preferences.

Make sure that you save the password to the volume when connecting, otherwise you'll have to enter on connecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: when we connect to a network drive using System Preferences, we actually specify the share to connect, so using the instructions such as on:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21600/mount-a-windows-share-in-os-x-and-have-it-reconnect-at-login/

We'd actually specify to connect to

```
smb://synology.local/Public
smb://synology.local/Backup
```

or any other shares at system start up.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant